# Curved Tabbar indicator decoration in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to design like this image in flutter.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [flutter_colorful_tab](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_colorful_tab) library.

[image]

You can use it as is or if you like more exact UI you can change [this code](https://github.com/datdescartes/flutter_colorful_tab/blob/master/lib/flutter_colorful_tab.dart) to suit your needs

Comment: but as you see in screen shot it's curved from bottom but top , this what i am looking for